# Center map arround GeoPoints to set visible all them

Tags: c#, maps, uwp, win-universal-app, bing-maps

I'm using a MapControl to show some GeoPoints

XAML

```
<maps:MapControl x:Name="myMap">
...
</maps:MapControl>
```

C#

```
foreach (MapIcon icon in mapsIcons)
{
  myMap.MapElements.Add(icon);
}
```

I need to center and zoom the map automatically (or programatically) around all GeoPoints in the map in order to all the MapIcons are visible. Some way to do that?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list or array of BasicGeoposition's from your data and then pass them into the GeoboundingBox class:

```
var geoboundingBox = Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeoboundingBox.tryCompute(positions);
```

Then use this bounding box with the TrySetViewBounds of the map:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn637065.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn607971.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1